# Problem positioning HTML div below SVG appended to 'body' of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dom, leaflet

I have div in the body of my HTML that contains a map.  Also in the body of my HTML is script, in which I affix a d3 SVG canvas (another map!) to the HTML body.  So, two elements - the div which is created in HTML - and the SVG created in javascript d3.

The issue is that I cannot seem to place the HTML div below the SVG on the page.  My code is as follows:

```
<body>

<div class="container">  
    <!-- Title -->
    <h1 class="title has-text-centered">Text</h1>
    <h2 class="subtitle has-text-centered"></h2>

    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column is-half">
        <h2 class="subtitle has-text-centered" style="margin-left:-150px;"></h2>         
      </div>
     </div>
    <p class="subtitle is-5 has-text-centered" style="margin-top:0px">Random text</p>
</div>  
<!-- HTML map DIV -->
<div id="map" class="sf" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin-left: 250px" pointer-events="all"></div>

<script>
    // set up map
     var currentMap = d3.map();

     // load map data
     d3.queue()
        .defer(d3.csv, "data/statesProj.json", function(d) { 
        })
        .defer(d3.csv, "data/coworkingTenants_4.json", function(d) { 

        })
        .defer(d3.csv, "data/SFCounty_proj.json", function(c) { 
        })
        .defer(d3.csv, "data/SanFrancisco_CoWorkingTenants.json", function(cw) { 
        })
        .await(ready);

    function ready(error) {

    //load data to variable for d3 map
    var NationalData = coworkingTenantsNational.features
        console.log(NationalData)

    //predefine map height/width
    var width = 2070;
    var height = 600;

    // Create SVG and append to HTML body
    var svg = d3.select( "body" )
        .append( "svg" )
        .attr( "width", width )
        .attr( "height", height )
        .attr("class", 'subtitle is-5 has-text-centered')

    // Append empty placeholder g element to the SVG
    // g will contain geometry elements
    var g = svg.append( "g" );

    //projection
    var albersProjection = d3.geoAlbers()
        .scale( 1200)
        .rotate ( [98.5795,] )
        .center( [0, 39.8283] )

    //GeoPath
    var geoPath = d3.geoPath()
        .projection( albersProjection );

    //Draw the map in d3
    g.selectAll( "path" )
        .data( statesProj.features )
        .enter()
        .append( "path" )
        .attr( "fill", "black" )
        .attr( "d", geoPath )
        .attr("class","states");
     }

</script>


 </body>
```

A leaflet map goes into the #map HTML div, though I don't show that here.  I guess my question relates to how to manipulate the position of the HTML div relative to the SVG d3 element, given that the SVG element and the map DIV are being inserted into the HTML body in two different ways.  As is, the map DIV is on top of the SVG, and I'd like the map DIV to sit below it. Thanks all - apologies, but I'm a bit of a beginner in HTML and d3.js!

Comment: use `selection.insert()` instead of `.append()` to put svg before the div

Comment: Thank you!  This worked: .insert( "svg", "#map" )   Appreciate it.  (Although I accidentally un-did the upvote for your comment, and sadly I can't seem to upvote it... sorry!)